# UserManager - Access to Disposed Object

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Using ASP.NET Core 2.

I am trying to init some application-wide data. For that I created a new class called `DbInitializer`, an interface called `IDbInitializer`, and registered them with `AddScoped` in `Startup.ConfigureServices`.

Then from `Startup.Configure`, I call `DbInitializer.Initialize()` and inside that method there are a few calls to `UserManager`:

```
if (appDbContext.Roles.All(i => i.Name != adminGroupName))
{
    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(adminGroupName));
};
var role = appDbContext.Roles.First(i => i.Name == adminGroupName);

if (appDbContext.Users.All(i => i.UserName != adminSettings.Username))
{
    await userManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationUser { UserName = adminSettings.Username,
                                                        Email = adminSettings.Username,
                                                        FirstName = adminSettings.FirstName,
                                                        LastName = adminSettings.LastName,
                                                        EmailConfirmed = true }, adminSettings.Password);
}
var adminUser = appDbContext.Users.First(i => i.UserName == adminSettings.Username);

if (!appDbContext.UserRoles.Any(i => i.RoleId == role.Id && i.UserId == adminUser.Id))
{
    await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(adminUser, role.Name);
}
```

The problem is that I am getting, at random the exception

> Cannot access a disposed object

from `userManager.CreateAsync` or `userManager.AddToRoleAsync`.

Comment: Is DbInitializer.Initialize() async? Post it's prototype

Comment: Yes, it's declared in DbInitializer as: public async void Initialize()

Comment: Does renaming to public async Task Initialize() help?

Comment: Using Oracles MySQL Provider? It's broken and throws object disposed exception after the first query (first works, subsequent throw). Use Pomelo MySQL provider

Comment: I ended up removing all async code. Now it works. Thank you all.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the problem is that your `DbInitializer.Initialize()` method call (which should be marked `async` and return a `Task`) is not properly being awaited, since the `Startup.Configure` method must return void. It should work if you change your call to be `DbInitializer.Initialize().Wait()` which will wait for the task to complete.